# How to query specific custom post with custom fields in a post_type?

Tags: wordpress

I'm new into wordpress and kinda confused how to get 1 post in a custom post. I only knew the loop where it echo all the content in a post_type.

I'm aiming to get 1 post from a post_type 'product-category' and the meta_key is 'product-category-and-type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query for custom in wordpress:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'product-category',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            "numberposts"   => 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'product-category-and-type',
                    'value' => 'meta_value'
                )
            )
        );

        $getPosts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and paste below mentioned code at your desired position and replace "your_meta_value" with your actual meta value for meta key "product-category-and-type".

You will get your expected result :

```
<?php $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'product-category',
            "numberposts"   => 1,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'product-category-and-type','value' => 'your_meta_value'))
            );

        $myposts = new WP_Query($args); 
        while($myposts->have_posts()) : $myposts->the_post();
        the_title();
         endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product-category',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product-category-and-type',
            'field'    => 'slug'
        ),
    ),
);

$result = new WP_Query($args);
```